# android studio gradle build

Tags: android, gradle

I am using latest version of android studio 
and i am open a an older project the android studio not open this project
and always fininshing the gradle while downloading or building it 
i have attached the screen shot with this for batter understanding
please help me on this issue these project was build with older android studio like 2.2 and now i am using the latest version which is android 2.3.3 but with this version project was not open properely

android gradle problem the screen shot of the problem

[image: android gradle problem the screen shot of the problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This same thing happened to me, when i was into android. Go to android sdk manager and update whatever it says, and you will good to go.

Even android studio is also trying to do the same thing. but it doesn't show you the progress.

Comment: with the older version it works fine and open my project with out delay but when i try to update the android studio it is not opening same project in new version it delays the project while the bar which i provided the screen shot appers and i waite 4hr to open the project but nothing heppend when i use older version it is open quickly

Comment: i am unaware of your environment but update your android sdk, it will work. even i faced the same problem keeping it to refresh the whole night.